# K. Houston complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers

Does anyone have Kevin Houston's *Complex Analysis* with all the pictures inside? My lecturer recommended me this book but the thing is that I found only 2004/2005 edition *without* any pictures! And that drives me crazy because there are many great examples and exercises but I cannot see them visually.

Help me!

Comment: How do you know there are pictures in that book? I am looking at it right now and I can't find yet one single note for a picture or anything like that...

Comment: Example 12.2 on pg. 55 @DonAntonio

Comment: and again page 57: ‘Now, consider the complicated contour image DRAWN BELOW with a line passing through it’ and there is an empty space below :)))

Comment: You are right. Also the copy I have doesn't have any pictures...

Comment: @DonAntonio It's reasonable for the OP to believe that there are pictures in the book since the author says [he's a geometer](http://www.kevinhouston.net/blog/2013/03/what-is-the-best-proof-of-cauchys-integral-theorem/) and "every proof should have a picture".